# Calling sbatch on an executable that calls srun

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, slurm, sbatch

If I have a bash script that contains the sbatch options that specify the resources that need to be available before running the script, and in that script, instead of a series of srun commands, I have an executable that calls srun multiple times.

Will the calls to srun from the executable use the same resources that were allocated by sbatch when it was called on the script or be treated as completely independent calls to srun?

Is it possible to use the calculation power of CPUs from different nodes to run in parallel the srun commands that are called by the executable, knowing that the actions performed by the calls are completely independent?

Comment: Why does the sbatch script need to call srun repeatedly?

Comment: @pcamach2 it doesn't need to, but calls to srun inside sbatch's script make it possible to execute job steps, also with srun's command line options you can choose the amount of the resources allocated by sbatch you want to affect towards the execution of the job step.